CUDA Out of Memory on a Reinforcement Learning algorithm
import os
import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from tqdm import tqdm
from TTset_main import load_TTset

# Load the dataset
filted_tset_path = "training_path.csv"
filted_vset_path = "validation_path.csv"
TTset_training, TTset_vali, training_data_length = load_TTset(filted_tset_path, filted_vset_path)

# Custom Dataset Class
class VideoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_list):
        self.data_list = data_list
        self.length = sum(len(video[0]) for video in data_list)  # Total number of frames

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        video_idx = 0
        frame_idx = idx
        # Find the corresponding video and frame
        for video, labels in self.data_list:
            if frame_idx < len(video):
                frame = video[frame_idx]
                label = labels[frame_idx]
                return frame, label
            frame_idx -= len(video)
        raise IndexError("Index out of range")

# Create DataLoader
batch_size = 1  # One frame at a time
video_dataset = VideoDataset(TTset_training)
data_loader = DataLoader(video_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

# CNN Model
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*30*115*115, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 64*30*115*115)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

# Training Loop
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = CNNModel(num_classes=20).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Training with progress bar
total_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(total_epochs):
    training_acu_count = 0  # Reset the accuracy count for each epoch
    for i, (x, y) in tqdm(enumerate(data_loader)):
        model.train()
        x = x.to(device).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension
        y = y.to(device)
        pred = model(x)
        t_loss = loss_function(pred, y.unsqueeze(0))  # Match dimensions for loss calculation
        t_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        pred_convert = torch.argmax(pred, 1)
        training_acu_count += (pred_convert == y).sum().item()

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{total_epochs}, Training Accuracy: {training_acu_count/len(video_dataset):.4f}")

# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "video_classification_model.pth")


I'm using the above code to train a RL model that classifies videos. The TTset_training is a dataloader object that contains inputs and targets. Input dimensions are 129x15x3x60x230x230, and target dimensions are 129x15. The video frames are tensors of dimensions 3x60x230x230.
I'm running this code on a 4070Ti, and I'm getting the following error:
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 48.43 GiB. GPU

I've tried multiple tweaks, changing batch size, using a loop to input data individually, but no luck. I've searched online for solutions but all of them recommend changing the size of the frames, which is not possible as I would lose a lot of data.

Take a look at the traceback you are getting. To have a reproducible example, I reduced your code to this:


import os

import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader




# CNN Model
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv3d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv3d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*30*115*115, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.max_pool3d(x, 2)
        x = x.view(-1, 64*30*115*115)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

# Training Loop
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = CNNModel(num_classes=20).to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

I get the following traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 33
     31 # Training Loop
     32 device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
---> 33 model = CNNModel(num_classes=20).to(device)
     34 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
     35 loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

File ~\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\clustering\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1145, in Module.to(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1141         return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1142                     non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
   1143     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)
-> 1145 return self._apply(convert)

File ~\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\clustering\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:797, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    795 def _apply(self, fn):
    796     for module in self.children():
--> 797         module._apply(fn)
    799     def compute_should_use_set_data(tensor, tensor_applied):
    800         if torch._has_compatible_shallow_copy_type(tensor, tensor_applied):
    801             # If the new tensor has compatible tensor type as the existing tensor,
    802             # the current behavior is to change the tensor in-place using `.data =`,
   (...)
    807             # global flag to let the user control whether they want the future
    808             # behavior of overwriting the existing tensor or not.

File ~\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\clustering\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:820, in Module._apply(self, fn)
    816 # Tensors stored in modules are graph leaves, and we don't want to
    817 # track autograd history of `param_applied`, so we have to use
    818 # `with torch.no_grad():`
    819 with torch.no_grad():
--> 820     param_applied = fn(param)
    821 should_use_set_data = compute_should_use_set_data(param, param_applied)
    822 if should_use_set_data:

File ~\AppData\Local\mambaforge\envs\clustering\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1143, in Module.to.<locals>.convert(t)
   1140 if convert_to_format is not None and t.dim() in (4, 5):
   1141     return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None,
   1142                 non_blocking, memory_format=convert_to_format)
-> 1143 return t.to(device, dtype if t.is_floating_point() or t.is_complex() else None, non_blocking)

RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

which states that the issue is in model = CNNModel(num_classes=20).to(device), so it is already your model that is too large for your GPU, it has nothing to do with training.
nn.Linear(64*30*115*115, 512)

will take up a huge amount of memory, as the weight matrix will be 64*30*115*115*512 entries large. At 4 bytes per entry, this gives roughly 48 GB of GPU memory required.
So you will need to rethink your model.
